# Pega: How do I use Connect-File method?

Tags: pega

I want to create a text file on Pega local system and write some content in it. For that  i am using Connect-File method. I have a parameter to specify there, "destination path". I don't know what destination path to give because the environment that I am using i don't know in which server it is hosted. When i give, "/tmp", it says it is not an absolute path. Any clue ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Do you know which OS is running on the server Pega is running on? It it is Unix / Linux a path like

> /tmp/

is an absolute path. According to the [PDN article](https://pdn.pega.com/sites/pdn.pega.com/files/help_v719/procomhelpmain.htm#rule-/rule-connect-/rule-connect-file/service.htm) on a windows system the path should be like

> C:\temp

Do you get an error when saving the rule or later when executing the Connect-File? If the error occurs while executing, maybe you forgot to provide a filename as parameter.